# Removing characters and changing color of text in label doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want to replace every word starting with `%` with the same word without the `%` and changing its color to green.

However, all I can do is remove the `%` without changing colors.

Is there something I am missing here?

```js
var text = "Lite %match Color"
text = text.replace(/%(.*?)/g, "<span style='color: green'>$1</span>")
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = text
```

```html
<label id="output"></label>
```

Comment: If you have to match only one word, instead of `.*?` you could use `\S+`

Comment: Markup in `<textarea>` doesn't work. You might want to consider a "content editable" solution.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Next time take more care with the description. I hammer closed with a dupe because you mentioned a textarea in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that, given that you have no lookahead after the `.*?`, it will match the least amount of characters, which is none at all. In order to fix this problem, you can substitute that part with `\S+`, that attempts to match any non-space characters (at least one).

```js
var text = "Lite %match Color"
text = text.replace(/%(\S+)/g, "<span style='color: green'>$1</span>")
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = text
```

```html
<label id="output"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = "Lite %match Color"
  text = text.replace(/\s+%(.*?)\s+/g, "<span style='color: green'> $1 </span>")
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = text
```

```html
<div id="output"> </div>
```

Comment: The subject was not right, its a `span` not a `textarea`. I was able to make it change color before with this `text = text.replace(/(%match.*?)/gi, "<span style='color: green'>$1</span>") ` but it didnt replace the `%`.

Comment: your suggestion doesnt do anything. It doesnt even remove the `%` I am afraid.

Comment: it removed the `%` and add the word in span with green color, this is the question description, you can run the code snippet and see.